# Any way to trigger mysql functions automatic on specific time? on mysql 5.0.91-log

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to trigger mysql functions automatic on specific time? on mysql 5.0.91-log
and is there any way to do this on php?
i mean a php page that will set mysql to do something on a specific time?
thank you very much!

Comment: Ever heard of `crontab`? If not, readup ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: You could also consider upgrading to 5.1 or better so you can use the built-in [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

Comment: my site is stored on ipage servers... how can i update to 5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cron job to execute your php at a specific time. Your php would call the mysql stored procedure.

Comment: What is mysql stored procedure? and can you please give me alink to a guide for cronjob to my mysql version? thank you very much!

Comment: Why even go through php when you can simply call the stored procedure directly via `mysql`?

Comment: @Femaref: Besides Events (which are noy available at 5.0) how can you call something via mysql, repeatedly, say every 10 minutes? Or do you mean that crontab should call directly the mysql procedure (bypassing PHP)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. No need to have php in there.

Comment: I need to check for example:
if team_score_one from bettable is greater than team_score_two
then increase points WHERE .......
can i do that directly from mysql every 1 hour?
if so, then please tell me how. thank you all!